# how can we call the wallpaper name on actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing an app of wallpapers. With button clicks images change perfectly. I want to display the name of image or as wallpaper#1, then to the next and son on and I want this in place of action bar. I have completely no idea about it. What I have to do means (call the action bar every time) or need a layout over imageview. First look at my xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="fill" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="100" > 
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:background="#66FFFFFF"
    android:maxHeight="91dip"
    android:maxWidth="47dip"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/r0" /> 
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bprev"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Back" >
    </Button>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bnext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="Next" > 
    </Button> 
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

And here is Main Activity.

```
 public class Main extends Activity { 

   private ImageView hImageViewPic;
   private Button iButton, gButton; 
   private int currentImage = 0;

  int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 }; 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
    iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);
    gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bprev); 
       //Just set one Click listener for the image 
    iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener);
    gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);
        }
    View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         //Increase Counter to move to next Image
      currentImage++; 
      currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
      hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
        } 
   };  
      View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
          //Increase Counter to move to next Image 
       currentImage--; 
       currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
       hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
        }
     };
   }
```

Plz give me solution to get this target. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Hidden actionbar id.

**Grab the ID for the action_bar_title**

```
int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");

Now you can use the ID with a TextView

TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId);
yourTextView.setTextColor(colorId);
```

Comment: Thanx for reply. Sir I put this code in Main_Activity but no results. I am new to andriod. Can you plz guide me with details.